# Ordereddict Merge by Month, and Week python

Tags: python

My Ordereddict is

```
month = OrderedDict([('Jan', 23), ('Dec', 5), ('Sep', 2), ('Oct', 233)])
```

I want this sort by month.

```
OrderedDict([('Jan', 23), ('Sep', 2), ('Oct', 233), ('Dec', 5)])


week = OrderedDict([('1-4', 5), ('34-38', 53), ('30-32', 3), ('13-20', 33)])
```

here the 1-4, 34-38 are week of years.

I want this sort by week as

```
OrderedDict([('1-4', 5), ('13-20', 33), ('30-32', 3), ('34-38', 53)])

date = OrderedDict([('2/23/2013', 5), ('1/13/2013', 33), ('1/22/2013', 3), ('1/3/2013', 53)])
```

Comment: Sort by month: Why not store the month's number, not the short name? For the second case: How is the sorting for the week defined? How do you sort `['1-4', '2-3', '2-7', '8-10']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`calendar.month_abbr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_abbr) with `sorted` function :

```
>>> import calendar
>>> l=list(list(calendar.month_abbr))
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(month.items(),key=lambda x:l.index(x[0])))
OrderedDict([('Jan', 23), ('Sep', 2), ('Oct', 233), ('Dec', 5)])
```

Here you need to apply the `sorted` function on `month.itms()` and sort its elements based on the months index in `calendar.month_abbr` :

```
>>> list(calendar.month_abbr)
['', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

And for weeks you just need to sort based on the first part of the week range:

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(week.items(),key=lambda x:x[0].split('-')[0]))
OrderedDict([('1-4', 5), ('13-20', 33), ('30-32', 3), ('34-38', 53)])
```

And for date format like `'2/23/2013'` use `datetime.datetime.strptime` as your `sorted` key:

```
>>> import datetime 
>>> date = OrderedDict([('2/23/2013', 5), ('1/13/2013', 33), ('1/22/2013', 3), ('1/3/2013', 53)])
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(date.items(),key=lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0],'%d/%M/%Y')))
OrderedDict([('1/3/2013', 53), ('1/13/2013', 33), ('1/22/2013', 3), ('2/23/2013', 5)])
```

Comment: Having another doubt, if the key value is date how to sort that. for example date =  OrderedDict([('2/23/2013', 5), ('1/13/2013', 33), ('1/22/2013', 3), ('1/3/2013', 53)])